# Degree of a coherent sheaf after a blow up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

Let $Y$ be a smooth projective scheme and $X$ a projective subscheme of $Y$. 
Let us consider the blowup morphism of $Y$ along $X$, denotated by $\pi_{X} : \widetilde{Y} \longrightarrow Y$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf of rank $r$ in $Y$ and $\widetilde{\mathcal{F}} = \pi_{X}^{*}(\mathcal{F})$.

What is the definition of $\text{deg}(\widetilde{\mathcal{F}})$? Does the exceptional divisor contribute to the $\text{deg}(\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}) $ "calculation"? Is there any relationship between $\text{deg}(\widetilde{\mathcal{F}})$ and $\text{deg}(\mathcal{F})$?

References and suggestions on this subject will be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Degree makes sense only if you fix an ample line bundle. There is no natural ample line bundle on the blow up in general.

Comment: @Mohan. Thanks for your response.  Can we consider  $\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{Y}}(1)$  playing the role of an ample bundle?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{Y}}(1)$? Some arbitrary ample line bundle?

Comment: I'm interested in the case that $ Y = \mathbb{P}^{n}$. Excuse me but I'm a beginner at Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: Do you know any references on this subject that can help me? When it comes to blow up  I find few answers.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is even if you fix an ample bundle on $Y$, there is no natural ample line bundle on the blow up and without it the degree is meaningless.

Comment: Ok, Mohan. Thank you !!